# Azure AD: cannot handle missing claims

Tags: vb.net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a legacy Vb.Net WebForms application. It uses Azure AD (for employees) and Azure AD B2C (for customers) for authentication. B2C returns some custom claims, which AD does not return. Here is some code that should retrieve the claims:

```
  If Request.IsAuthenticated Then

        Dim claims = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims


        Dim name As String = claims?.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Type.Equals("name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.Value

        Dim userName As String = claims?.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Type.Equals("emails", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.Value

        Dim userTypes As String = claims?.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Type.Equals("extension_UserTypes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.Value
```

Here, extension_UserTypes is the custom claim. When a customer logs in, all three claims are retrieved successfully. But when an employee logs in, only the first two claims are retrieved, and the 3rd custom claim throws an exception:

> Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: username
>
> at System.Web.Util.SecUtility.CheckParameter(String& param, Boolean checkForNull, Boolean checkIfEmpty, Boolean checkForCommas, Int32 maxSize, String paramName)
> at System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
> at System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.GetRoles()
> at System.Web.Security.RoleClaimProvider.<get_Claims>d__4.MoveNext()
> at System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity.<get_Claims>d__51.MoveNext()
> at System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.<get_Claims>d__37.MoveNext()
> at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()

The same exception happens if I use ForEach on claims.

How can I deal with this issue? I need to be able at least to check if extension_UserTypes custom claim is there. I tried

```
Dim exists = claims.Any(Function(c) c.Type = "extension_UserTypes")
```

but got the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claims retrieval code is fine, the stack trace states the problem already exists during a call to `SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(userName)`. Locate the dbo.aspnet_Users row the affected record/user and replace the null `userName` value.

Comment: But it is this line Dim userTypes As String = claims?.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Type.Equals("extension_UserTypes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.Value that causes the trouble. Without it no exception happens. And I have no idea what this has to do with some SqlRoleProvider, or what userName it is talking about.

Comment: Yes because it relies on the one signaled in my answer. If you're not using the SqlRoleProvider then remove it from your web.config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.sqlroleprovider?view=netframework-4.8#examples